# Magento Customer Collection for Gender

Tags: magento

I have tried to create the new customer account using my custom module.I need to store the Gender along with customer account creation. Here is collection for i have tried to Store Gender.

```
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        $customer->setData('firstname', $data['first_name']);
        $customer->setData('lastname', $data['last_name']);
        $customer->setData('email', $data['email']);
        $customer->setData('gender', $data['gender']);
        $customer->setData('is_active', 1);
        $customer->setData('confirmation', null);
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->getGroupId();
        $customer->save();
```

In this collection first name, last name and email are saved properly in customer table. 
But gender information is not saved in customer table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides two minor errors (double setting of `confirmation`, obsolete `getGroupId`) this should work.

My guess would be that you're using the wrong option id for gender in `$data['gender']`.

Try with a fixed gender value to check this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setFirstname('John')
    ->setLastname('Doe')
    ->setEmail('51zv52zg@example.com')
    ->setGender(
        Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')
            ->getAttribute('gender')
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionId('Female')
    )
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setConfirmation(null)
    ->save();
```